# Identify & replace 2nd instance of search term in string... VBA RegEx doesn't have lookbehind functionality

Tags: regex, excel, string, vba, duplicates

I have a list of strings in format as below :

```
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 250PS xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 350PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 200PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 200PS xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 250PS xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 350PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx
```

In Excel/VBA, and I am trying to remove duplicate values from the string i.e. 100PS and 200PS where it is printed out twice. Using VBA and Reg-Ex I've come up with :

```
(?<=\d\d\dPS\s.*)(\d\d\dPS\s)
```

And this seems to work when testing it online and on other languages, but in VBA, lookbehind is not supported, and this is absolutely wrecking my brain.

The value always consists of \d\d\d (3 digits) and PS, ends with \s but all the xxxxxx text around it can differ every time and have different lengths etc.

How would I possibly choose the duplicate PS value with regex?

I have looked through stackoverflow and found a couple of reg-ex examples, but they don't seem to be working in VBA..

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: you regex doesn't currently look for duplicates, so in a line like `xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx 200PS xxxxxxx xxxxxx`, `200PS` would be removed. Is this deliberate?

Comment: You are probably going to have to split the string on a space then either filter or loop an instr on the original string for each element of the array.

Comment: Try using `\s(\d{3}PS)\s.*\s\1(?=\s)`

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use  [`(\d{3}PS).*(?=\d{3})(\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/TWTKRp/1) and then if you have a match in group2 to replace it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for such a fast reply,
@cybernetic.nomad it is always on one line and duplicate value i.e. `xxxx xxxx 100PS xxxx 100PS xxxxx` or it would be `xxxx xxxxxxx 200PS xxxx xxx 200PS xxxx`

so the value on the same line is always the same, I just want to remove the second(last) occurance of `\d\d\dPS\s`

Comment: @Jeeped As it is possible with the lookbehind method, I was certain that no loop etc. is required and this is can be done strictly with regex highlighting/matching the second instance and then accordingly handle the data in VBA.

Comment: @ctwheels I tried the code you sent, it chooses everything from first 200PS to last 200PS and everything inbetween.

Comment: @Bubba are you trying to replace just the second duplicate?

Comment: @ctwheels yes, I am only trying to match second duplicate and remove that.

If you could check on [link]www.regexr.com  and use the lookbehind value i provided `(?<=\d\d\dPS\s.*)(\d\d\dPS\s)`
you'll see what I mean as it works as intended on there, but not anywhere else :/

Comment: @Bubba gotcha, try this then: [`(\s(\d{3}PS)\s.*\s)\2\s` replace with `$1`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cs%28%5cd%7b3%7dPS%29%5cs.*%5cs%29%5c2%5cs&i=xxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxx+100PS+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxx+xxxxxx%0d%0axxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxx+100PS+xxxxxxxxxxxxx+100PS+xxxxxxx+xxxxxx%0d%0axxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxx+200PS+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+200PS+xxxxxxxxx+xxxxxx&r=%241)

Comment: @ctwheels I think you've hit it on the head with that one, I will double check and run in my program and let you know if it works, you'll hear a reply from me within next hour or so :) 

Thank you again so much for helping me out!

Comment: @ctwheels thank you so much, it works perfectly as intended! 

Can I accept this as an answer as it is what I required (regex) even though I understand, the person below has answered correctly but it is a worksheet formula. 

Both are correct though and does exactly what is needed! thank you

Comment: @Bubba posted as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cs%28%5Cd%7B3%7DPS%29%5Cs.*%5Cs%29%5C2%5Cs&i=xxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20100PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20250PS%20xxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20350PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20100PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20100PS%20xxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20200PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20200PS%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20100PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20250PS%20xxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxx%0D%0Axxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20350PS%20xxxxxxxxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxxx%20xxxx&r=%241)

```
(\s(\d{3}PS)\s.*\s)\2\s
```

- `(\s(\d{3}PS)\s.*\s)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\s` Matches a single whitespace character
  - `(\d{3}PS)` Capture the following into capture group 2

    - `\d{3}` Matches any 3 digits
    - `PS` Match this literally
  - `\s` Matches a single whitespace character
  - `.*` Matches any character (except `\n`) any number of times
  - `\s` Matches a single whitespace character
- `\2` Matches the text that was most recently captured by capture group 2
- `\s` Matches a single whitespace character

Replacement: `$1` (puts capture group 1 back into the string)

Result:

```
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 250PS xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 350PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 200PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 100PS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 250PS xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx 350PS xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a worksheet formula?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,SEARCH("???PS",A1),6),"",2)
```

[image]

Comment: If this works, I will genuinely smack the keyboard off my own face.

Will this work in any case where the same value is duplicated i.e. if the value is anything else but 100 or 200PS?(350PS, 400PS etc. etc.)

Comment: The thing is, the length can differ from 26 and 31 string in position.. I just copy and pasted the xxxxx lines to show what I mean by second duplicate, which I appreciate you have actually solved the data given.. But the data given isn't a exact representation of the data i.e. string length/character positions.

Comment: No they are other things, sensitive information hence why I used xxxx to mask the actual data

Comment: @Bubba, I've updated the formula. It works for all requirements now :)

Comment: Thank you @CallumDA
I will run both, this worksheet formula and the regex provided by ctwheels and see which one is more efficient/faster.

Thank you!